# Security concern of Next.js SSR site

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, next.js, server-side-rendering

I have a community blogging website where authenticated users can post blogs developed on Next.js. On sign-in, the user gets a cookie (which is a JWT encrypted using cryptojs) and a session token - which gets saved in localstorage of the browser. Client application talks with the server using REST APIs. On each API request the client app adds the cookie (by default) and session token (for CSRF attacks mitigation). It works great where the application has to use CSR, but doesn't work for SSR (while fetching blog content etc.) cases as localstorage is not accessible in SSR.

Currently, the blogs are public and anyone can read it but after sometime I have to make it private, accessible only to authenticated/premium users. Also, currently the application has to make 2 API calls to the server to fetch the blog content and user's likes status as the prior one is public but for the secondary we need user's login status. As both will be one-by-one API calls, I don't think it will take so much time because of `keep-alive` (can we try some other solution except this?).

I have few doubts/questions regarding this:

- Is there any way we can fetch localstorage in SSR? I was thinking of saving the localstorage in redux too but it will be null initially if user lands on the blog page directly (which eventually everyone would).
- Am I over-securing the application because the cookie follows all the possible security (https, same-site etc), still I use `x-xsrf-token` to mitigate XSRF attacks which gets saved in browser's localstorage?
- Is XSRF attack possible in SSR? I guess, it will be. Though, the application doesn't do any transaction on `GET` calls (which is the main cause of XSRF - AFAIK), I'm worried about the security. Next.js collaborator [suggests to use cookie for authentication](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/16824) but what if the cookie gets shared somehow?

To increase security, I have encrypted the generated JWT token. I know it's an overhead but it's onetime charge so I'm kind of fine with it.

Should I re-think about using some other auth layer logic?

Comment: You can't access localStorage in SSR, using cookies would be my suggestion too. What do you mean by "what if the cookie gets shared somehow"? How would that happen?

Comment: Currently, the app uses Cookies+XSRF token for authentication for all the requests like profile fetching, blog submission etc. Should I change this to use only cookies? but as cookies are automatically sent, will that not be a security concern for attacks like XSRF? If I use this method, authentication on SSR won't work. I can provide a master XSRF token to the SSR methods probably?

Comment: @juliomalves the wording that I used was probably confusing. I meant with "what if the cookie gets shared somehow" is that, I'm still in doubt. As the cookies are auto-sent, will cookie theft be possible if someone frames the site in their content? or tries to use the API calls used in the site and target users for phishing?